# Implications of skewed data In when performing Linear regression

Tags: regression, multiple-regression

What are the implications of skewed data in your explanatory variables when performing Linear regression?

Is there an easy answer to this?

Comment: Aside from the possibility of highly influential points at the extreme tail, there's not necessarily any particular issue. What kind of things were you concerned about?

Comment: A more serious concern would be model errors having a skewed distribution. Meanwhile, regressors having skewed distribution does not seem to be a problem (except for influential points at the tail), as Glen_b indicates.